# How do I find a dictionary based off of one of its values in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm having difficulty with finding a dictionary based on one of its values, I'm trying to get it so the user inputs the 'Name' of one of my dictionary and it prints off all the other values but I don't know how.

heres the list Invintory

```
invintory = [ID001,ID002,ID003,ID004,ID005,ID006,ID007,ID008,ID009,ID010,ID011]
```

Heres an example of one of my dictionary's.

```
    ID001 = {
        'Name': 'A Dull Rusty Sword',
        'Weight': 5,
        'Price': 105,
        'Acc': 0,
        'Str': 3,
        'Dex': 0,
        'Hp': 0,
        'MagDmg': 0,
        'LevReq': 1
    }
```

This is the code I'm struggling with

```
print("")
for i, item in enumerate(invintory):  
  print("%d: %s" % (i, item['Name']))
print("")
invintioryOp = input("1 to see stats of an item, 2 to equip an item 3 to trash an item: ")
if int(invintioryOp) == 1:
  viewStats = input('Type the name of the item: ')
  #heres where I need help
```

Comment: Can you provide example(s) of what you are looking for?  And remove code not relevant to the question?

Comment: Can you show an example of what inventory data structure looks like?

Comment: I start reading your code and immediately ask myself: what's `invintory` [sic]?

Comment: Sorry for all the needed edits, still new to coding.

Comment: You're missing the keyword `if` before `int(invintioryOp) == 1:`

Comment: Opps diddent copy it correctly.

Comment: What problem are you having? Loop over the elements of `invintory`. Test if `item['Name']` equals the name the user entered. If it does, print all the fields of the item.

Comment: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Important technical note: Python doesn't have arrays, it has lists. And your example of an array is neither of those, it's a dictionary. (And this matters because knowing the right terms also lets you _search for solutions_ with the right terms)

Comment: Ok sorry, could you explain the differnces?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's a tuple actually

Comment: Whats a tuple?!

Comment: @CalvinMonty It is an immutable "list". Read more: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: @Barmar I dont understand what you mean, the thing I'm having differculty with is being able to identify the dictionaty based off of the value called 'Name' that the user inputs, then it needs to print off the rest of its values.

Comment: glanced too fast, you're right. An array is a data structure that represents a fixed sized list with each element being a fixed bytesized, coming to us from C and friends, with a very specific memory layout. Lists in Python are not fixed size, you can dynamically add or remove elements, nor is there any requirement for the elements to be the same. A tuple is an immutable list, where now we _can't_ add or remove elements, but elements still don't have to be the same thing in the slightest. But the important part here is knowing what things are called so you can search for answers.

Comment: `if item['Name'] == viewStats:`

Comment: @HelloHello Ok thanks, I'll read though this.

Comment: (which you should of course do now that you know the correct terms =D)

Comment: @Barmar What would this code accomplish?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So it is an array?

Comment: If you use it in a loop like `for item in invintory:` it will tell you if the current item matches what the user is searching for.

Comment: `invintory` is a tuple. In Python, `()` surrounds tuples, `[]` surrounds lists, and `{}` surrounds dictionaries and sets.

Comment: @CalvinMonty: no, arrays are a way to organize elements with the same byte size in memory. Since you can't guarantee those dicts have the same bytesize, even if the tuple can't be modified, its content is nothing like what an array requires. It's _similar_ to an array in that it's fixed length but that's pretty much where the similarities end.

Comment: @Barmar Ok so the issue is I dont want to see if the 2 are the same I have 121 lists or dictionarys of arrays or whatever they are, I need it so that the user inputs the name of one of the dictionarys and it prints off all the other values in the dictionary

Comment: See the linked question, it shows how to search a list of dictionaries for one that matches the search key.

Comment: You have a tuple of dictionaries. Not "whatever", we're not here for "I don't care what it is I just want a fix", you posted here to learn =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans So this would be a tuple?

Comment: `invintory` is a tuple, and all elements in that tuple (`ID001` etc), based on your description and code you showed, are dictionaries.

Comment: Why wouldent invintory be a list?

Comment: No. You are calling things arrays, and there are no arrays in Python.

Comment: Because of the code you're showing, which uses the Python syntax for declaring a tuple by using `(...)`. If it should be a list, you should use `[...]` instead.

Comment: @CalvinMonty It would be a list if you wrote `invintory = [...]`. Didn't you see my earlier comment about the difference between tuples, lists, dictionaries and sets?

Comment: This is all basic Python syntax, it should be explained in your tutorial.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so as a tuple I cant edit it?

Comment: You've been told that several times now, yes. Please reread the entire comment thread before posting more questions.

Comment: Ok, so I think I understand Lists, Dictionays and tuples.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans could you help me understand the anser that was provided?

Comment: At this point it firmly sounds like you're unfamiliar with basic Python so instead I'm going to suggest the official Python tutorial over on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html - run through that, at the very least up to and including chapter 5. Because without that foundation, no answers you get (now or in the future) will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you meant is  an array of objects like:

```
yourArray = [
      {name: 'Name1', height:'6ft', ...},
      {name: 'Name2', height:'6ft', ...},
      {name: 'Name3', height:'6ft', ...},
    ];
```

In that case, you can follow the following code snippet.

```
yourArray = [
  {name: 'Name1', height:'6ft', ...},
  {name: 'Name2', height:'6ft', ...},
  {name: 'Name3', height:'6ft', ...},
]

#lets say, user input is
userInput = 'Name1';
foundArray = None; #here initialize a null variable

for array in yourArray:
    if array['Name'] == userInput:
        foundArray = array; #assign the found array to the variable
        break;

if foundArray:
    print(f"Name: {foundArray['name']}");
    print(f"height: {foundArray['height']}");
    #...other values
else:
    print(f"No array with the name '{userInput}' found.");
```

Comment: You don't need the `foundArray` variable. Put the printing code inside `if`, and use the `else:` block of the `for` loop to execute something if it ends without `break`.

Comment: Thnaks so much!